# probability of a limiting sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $U_i$ are uniformly distributed on (0,1) and are independent. For all possible increasing index sets comprising the family $J$, I am trying to show that

$P(\cap_{j\in J} \{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_{j_k}}{n}\} = \frac{1}{2}) = 0.$

My attempt is as follows: denote by $A_i = \{\omega \in \Omega:\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_{i_k}}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\}$.

Then instead of showing that $P(\cap A_i) = 0,$ I can show that $P(\cup A_i^c) = 1.$

However, $P(\cup A_i^c) \le \sum P(A_i^c)$.

Now, there's a theorem which says that if $U_i$'s are iid, $E[U_i] = \mu$ and $E[U_i^4] < \infty$ then $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ has the property that $S_n/n \rightarrow \mu$ a.s.

In the above case, $P(A_i) = 1$ because of the above theorem implying that $P(A_i^c) = 0$. This contradicts what I am supposed to prove.

Any thoughts or hints? One hint given is to use the fact that $\{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ are dense in $(0,1)$ save for a set of measure 0. But I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is simpler to explain when $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(X_i=0)=P(X_i=1)=\frac12$. For every $j$ in $J$, let $S_n^j=X_{j_1}+X_{j_2}+\cdots+X_{j_n}$ and $$A_j=\{\lim\limits_{n}\tfrac1nS_n^j=1/2\}.$$ Let $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and $Z(\omega)=\{n\mid X_n(\omega)=0\}\subseteq\mathbb N$.

- Either $Z(\omega)$ is infinite then $j=Z(\omega)$ yields $S_n^j(\omega)=0$ for every $n$ hence $\omega$ is not in $A_j$ because $\lim\limits_{n}\tfrac1nS_n^j(\omega)=0$.
- Or $Z(\omega)$ is finite then $j=\mathbb N$ yields $S_n^j(\omega)\geqslant n-|Z(\omega)|$ for every $n$ hence $\omega$ is not in $A_j$ because $\lim\limits_{n}\tfrac1nS_n^j(\omega)=1$.

This proves that, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, there exists $j$ in $J$ such that $\omega$ is not in $A_j$, that is, $$\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j=\varnothing.$$
in particular, the set on the LHS is an event and its probability is zero. (Note that the appearance of the empty set on the RHS of this identity is fortunate since one cannot know a priori that the set on the LHS, being an uncountable intersection of events, is an event.)

Can you adapt this to the case when $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$?

Comment: I think I got the idea, thanks Did. But what's wrong with my solution above? Why did it give me something contradictory to what I'm supposed to prove? I can't find the flaw to it...

Comment: You applied additivity to the uncountable family $(A_j^c)_{j\in J}$ and, for that, Kolmogorov *might strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger*... :-)

Comment: Did, while thinking about it, I realized it's not straightforward to adapt the above to the U(0,1) case. It doesn't make sense to talk about $X_j = 0.5$ or something because these are continuous RVs. Is this where I invoke the fact that the $X_k$'s are dense in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Right, one does not copy the above, one *adapts* it, but frankly, the adaptation is not *that* difficult.